# I want to get image and json data together from node server called by angular client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

How to embedded image file in json data. Client side code:

```
 $http.get('http://localhost/get_data')
         .success( function(res) {
          $scope.get_data.image
 });
```

Server side code:

```
app.get('/get_data', function(req, res){
  var data = {
             name: "user1",
             lastname:"wilson",
             profilePic:'/image/user1.jpg'
  };

  res.send(req, res, data);
})
```

How to do this in the correct way to send data and get data please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can send response something like this:

```
app.get('/get_data,function(req,res){
var data={
       name: "user1",
       lastname:"wilson",
       profilePic:'/image/user1.jpg'
     }
     res.json(200,data)
 })
```

Comment: but i getting string only '/image/user1.jpg'  at angular side.but it should be a file